# Volume of a solid by triple integration

Tags: integration, volume

how can I solve this problem with triple integrations I have tried this but I don't get the true value

$\int_1^3\int_1^2\int_0^{x^2y^2}dzdydx$

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the planes $z = 0, x = 1, x = 3, y = 1, y = 2,$ and
surface $z = x^2y^2$?

I only want the triple integration in cartesian coordinates

Comment: what answer did you get?

Comment: The true value of the problem is $40/9$

Comment: Where is your work? what make you trouble? Show your working because people aren't interested to answer such question where you don't mention them particularly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral you have set up is correct for the problem as you have written it. Its value is $\frac{182}{9}$.

Either you've made a mistake transcribing the problem, or the "true answer" is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you are right

Comment: I am getting $182 \over 9$ but it's definitely not $40 \over 9$

Comment: Thank vasya $182/9$ is correct

Comment: You're right, 26 by 7 instead of 26 by 8.